# Defining function error using generics

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

Here's the code:

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
public func responseObject<T: ResponseJSONObjectSerializable> (completionHandler: (NSURLRequest?, NSHTTPURLResponse?, Result<T> -> Void) -> Self {
//Error1: expected ',' separator
//Error2: expected parameter type following ':'

    ...

)
}
```

I'm using Swift 2.0, Alamofire 3.0, and SwiftyJSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: there's a mistake of parenthesis in the code, the `)` should be place behind `result<T>` rather than the end of the function.

I thought it was some serious problem, took me a long time to find this. :P